# Route not found in Laravel even it exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to run an api on postman, I am getting the following error:

> Method not found

I created the controller and its route using laravel 5.7, I also checked whether the route exists using `php artisan route:list` command! I can get the route there. It is listed below is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Config;


class EletricityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    
    public function eletricityToken(Request $request){
      
        $client = new Client();
        $URL = Config('api.authUrl');
        $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer <token>'
        ];
        $options = [
        'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => Config('api.client_id'),
        'client_secret' => Config('api.client_secret'),
        'username' => Config('api.username'),
        'password' => Config('api.password'),
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'scope' => 'read write openid'
        ]];
        $request = new Request('POST', $URL, $headers);
        $res = $client->sendAsync($request, $options)->wait();
        echo $res->getBody();
    }
}
```

below is the route file:

```
Route::get('eletricityToken','Api\EletricityController@eletricityToken')->name('eletricityToken');
```

Comment: Did you try to define controller method in route with use not string just to make sure? `use App\Http\Controllers\Api\EletricityController;   Route::get('eletricityToken', [EletricityController::class, 'eletricityToken'])->name('eletricityToken');`

Comment: If you are making a POST request in Postman to the eletricityToken route, you should update your route definition to use the Route::post method instead of Route::get. Then run php artisan route:cache.

Comment: show the full error message and how you are sending the request and to what URL

Comment: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/eletrictyToken/" this is the url where I am sending the request, using get method, "resource not found!" thats the full error

Comment: this is a Laravel error mesesage or a webserver error message?

Comment: "Method not found"/ "resource not found!" are different. post the full error to check the path. Have you tryed to use http [in-build client](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#introduction)?

Comment: The full error is "  "message": "Not Found."" I sending the get request using this url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/eletricityToken"

Comment: laravel error message, when listing the routes I get the action as Closure

Comment: @MrChefane now I saw laravel 5.7, this very old (EOL in 2019), my answer won't help u.

Answer (score -1):

You can run `php artisan route:list` to see the list of routes and their corresponding controller methods.

I can remember that "`Route::get('eletricityToken','Api\EletricityController@eletricityToken')->name('eletricityToken');`" was allowed in old Laravel projects (version 5, maybe).

Try this

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\EletricityController;

...

Route::get('eletricityToken',[EletricityController::class,'eletricityToken'])->name('eletricityToken');
```

Please note to add `use App\Http\Controllers\Api\EletricityController;` immediately after the <?php in your route file.

Best of success

Answer (score -3):

On routes file(`web.php`/`api.php`), change the [route](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-default-route-files) like:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\EletricityController;

Route::get('/eletricityToken', [EletricityController::class, 'eletricityToken'])->name('eletricityToken');
```

Comment: There is no difference between them

Comment: @lezhni ofc it's different awnser added reference and readability get('/') vs get(''). NOT copy and paste

Comment: I mean there is no diff between `/electricityToken` and `electricityToken` in routes. I prefer to omit initial slash just because I can :)

Comment: @lezhni I follow what docs suggest for practice. Since [8.x](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing) they inserted the `/` in get. Still that `'Api\EletricityController@eletricityToken'` is old fashion way. If you want to stay away from problems you should follow what they suggest. docs don't lie.

Comment: Agreed with `callable` syntax anyway, it's a more native PHP-way